# Trouble detecting a touch on a nested custom sprite layer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have a layer, `HelloWorldLayer` below, where touch works anywhere, but I'd like it to work only when touching a sprite in the layer -- `turtle` below.

If I try to add `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;` onto the `CCTurtle` layer it says

> property `isTouchEnabled` not found on object type CCTurtle

my output reads as follows

2013-01-08 20:30:14.767 FlashToCocosARC[6746:d503] cocos2d: deallocing

2013-01-08 20:30:15.245 FlashToCocosARC[6746:d503] playing walk animation2

Here's my HelloWorldLayer code:

```
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "CCTurtle.h"

@implementation HelloWorldLayer

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
    [scene addChild: layer];
    return scene;
}

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        turtle= [[CCTurtle alloc] init];
        [turtle setPosition:ccp(300, 100)];
        [self addChild:turtle];
        ///addChild:child z:z tag:aTag;
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        turtle. tag=4;
    //

    }
return self;
}



//- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
//{
//    // Processing all touches for multi-touch support
//    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
//    if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[turtle class]]) {
//        NSLog(@"[touch view].tag = %d", [touch view].tag);
//        [self toggleTurtle];
//    }
//}
-(BOOL)containsTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGRect r=[turtle textureRect];
    CGPoint p=[turtle convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(r, p );
}
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //////GENERAL TOUCH SCREEN
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
        [self toggleTurtle];
        /////
    }

}
-(void) toggleTurtle
{
    NSLog(@"playing walk animation2");
   [turtle playAnimation:@"walk_in" loop:NO wait:YES];
}



@end
```

//hello world.h

```
    #import "cocos2d.h"
    #import "CCTurtle.h"

    @interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer 
    {
    CCTurtle                *turtle;
    }

    +(CCScene *) scene;

    @end
```

//CCturtle

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "FTCCharacter.h"

    @interface CCTurtle : FTCCharacter <FTCCharacterDelegate, CCTargetedTouchDelegate>
    {

    }
    @end
```

I'm using Cocos2D cocos2d v1.0.1 (arch enabled), and am testing on ipad 4.3 simulator. 
with thanks Natalie

ive tried to put the touches directly into ccturtle.m so it can handle its own touches using CCTargetedTouchDelegate as above but using

CCturtle/// I changed files to this trying a different way to find the touched area...

```
    - (CGRect)rect
   {
   CGSize s = [self.texture contentSize];
   return CGRectMake(-s.width / 2, -s.height / 2, s.width, s.height);
   }

   -(BOOL) didTouch: (UITouch*)touch {
   return CGRectContainsPoint(self.rect, [self convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:touch]);
   //return CGRectContainsPoint( [self rect], [self convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR: touch] );
   }

   -(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent: (UIEvent*)event {
   NSLog(@"attempting touch.");
   if([self didTouch: touch]) {
   return [self tsTouchBegan:touch withEvent: event];
   }
   return NO;
   }
```

but still wont compile as still returns the error **"Property 'is TouchEnabled' not found on object type 'CCTurtle*'**

am really not sure what i can do to get it to run now... and really need to get this working (i suppose i could make invisible buttons, but it would be nicer to be able to find the ccturtle properly and to understand what im doing wrong... hope someone can help

Comment: I am not very familiar with Cocos2D but if by saying "layer" you mean a subclass of `CALayer` then it is wrong approach. CALayer doesn't respond to touches. There is plenty of answers on this topic such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170288/trigger-an-action-when-a-calayer-is-touched

Comment: usually in cocos2d layer is an instance of CCLayer and it responds to touches.

Comment: Helloworld CCLayer is responding to the touches but FTCCharacter : CCSprite is not responding

Comment: Please post your .h file and what version of cocos2d you are using.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I cannot see anywhere calling of `containsTouch:` method. And here are several advices:

Use `boundingBox` instead of `textureRect` to get local rect of your node (your turtle, in this case). Or just replace `containsTouch:` method to your turtle class to incapsulate this. It can be helpful, for example, if you want to make touch area of your turtle bigger/smaller. You will just need to change one little method in your turtle class.

In your `ccTouchesBegan:withEvent:` method just check for every turtle if it is hit by this touch. Then, for example, you can create dictionary, with touch as the key and array of corresponding turtles as the value. Then you just need to update all turtles positions for moved touch in your `ccTouchesMoved:withEvent:` method and remove this array of turtles from the dictionary in `ccTouchesEnded:withEvent:` and ccTouchCancelled:withEvent: method.

Comment: try not to post code in the comments. it is very hard to read. and I still suggest to move `containsTouch:` method to the turtle class and call this check in your `ccTouchBegan:withEvent:` method

Comment: wow just discovered that!! :P have put the new method above, will try your bounding box with array now this didnt work sadly.

Comment: have moved the "contains touch" into "cctouch began with event method", ...no luck there, maybe using bounding box it will work though, ill try that! :)

Comment: Still quite stuck... am still trying to get it to work though

Comment: am happy to swap artwork for full working answer!! as really need to get this working i can make loading screens and other stuff too!) :D http://browse.deviantart.com/?q=mala-kocka

Comment: am happy to send project files, probably it is something fairly simple, as am VERY new to cocos2d and programming.

Comment: You can send the files to email on my profile. Let me know what version you are using.

Comment: @prototypical thanks!, cant find your email on your profile but my project is using github.com/TheDamArmada/Flash2Cocos2D, my helloworld layer code is different.

Comment: Ive tried to taret the touches in a differnt way (still the same problem of the ccturtle.h layer "Property 'is TouchEnabled' not found on object type 'CCTurtle*' :/

Comment: prototype.in.training at gmail - I need your code, not the github code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your CCTurtle object to accept targeted touches, you can do it by specifying that it conforms to the CCTargetedTouchDelegate protocol.  In your CCTurtle @interface, you declare it like so:

```
@interface CCTurtle : CCNode <CCTargetedTouchDelegate>
```

Then in the implementation, you tell it to accept touches and implement the ccTouch methods:

```
@implementation CCTurtle

-(id) init {
.
.
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:1 swallowsTouches:YES];
    return self;
}

-(void) onExit {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher removeDelegate:self];
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    CGPoint location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:[touch view]]];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([self boundingBox], location] {
        // some code here
    }
}


-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { // code here }
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { // code here}
-(void)ccTouchCancelled:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { // code here}
```

Comment: thankyou Sylvan for you help, sadly CCTurtle : FTCCharacter <FTCCharacterDelegate, CCTargetedTouchDelegate> return error property touch dispatcher not found on object CCDirector

Comment: @Natty What version of Cocos2D are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Cocos2D cocos2d v1.0.1 (arch enabled), and am testing on ipad 4.3 simulator

Comment: Ive tried to target the touches in a different way (still the same problem of the ccturtle.h layer "Property 'is TouchEnabled' not found on object type 'CCTurtle*' :/ I'm not sure how i would touch enable this layer

Comment: I'm thinking I might try simply to add a transparent button to control the animations on the characters! (i know probably not a very elegant solution!)I would prefer to get the touches working correctly, but for now this will probably be the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Prototypical the issue was solved, 
Although the CCTurtle was a layer with a type of sprite on it was nested sprites 
which meant that cocos2d had problems creating the correct bounding box for my
"contains touch method"

so with a bit of magic he combined his "[get full bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076037/need-a-bounding-box-for-ccsprite-that-includes-all-children-subchildren)" method to the contains touch method to account for the children of the sprite, and the code now relies on collision detection to process the touch.
currently im happily working away on some nice icons for him in return

but wanted to say thank-you to all that helped, and hope that this method comes in handy for anyone with the same problem!