# Create 3D cube with layers, with clickable sides - objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, uibutton, calayer

I'm now trying to create an application with a '3D cube', and clickable sides.

To create a '3D cube', i found a great article : [here](http://tumbljack.com/post/176535888/3d-objects-in-objective-c-with-catransformlayer)
It uses some 'layers'.

What i want to do, is done a cube in 3D, but with clickable sides. I found some examples like this :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([touches count] == 1) {
        for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
            CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
            point = [[touch view] convertPoint:point toView:nil];

            CALayer *layer = [(CALayer *)self.view.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:point];

            layer = layer.modelLayer;
            layer.opacity = 0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

But this sort of code makes no difference between the different sides. So I try to make some changes to the code from the article. For example, to create the first side, the code was :

```
CALayer *sideOne = [CALayer layer];
sideOne.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
sideOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.4].CGColor;
sideOne.borderWidth = Border_Width;
sideOne.cornerRadius = Corner_Radius;
sideOne.frame = layerRect;
sideOne.position = self.center;
```

and :

```
transformLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
[transformLayer addSublayer:test.layer];
transformLayer.anchorPointZ = Layer_Size/-2;
[rootLayer addSublayer:transformLayer];
```

So I try to make some modifications and finally add a 'UIButton' on this side. Like this :

```
UIButton * test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[test setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, layerSize, layerSize)];
[test addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionTest) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
test.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
test.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.4].CGColor;
test.layer.borderWidth = Border_Width;
test.layer.cornerRadius = Corner_Radius;
test.layer.frame = layerRect;
test.layer.position = self.center;
```

But the problem is, when i want to add it to the side.

When i do :

```
transformLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
[self addSubview:test];
[transformLayer addSublayer:test.layer];
transformLayer.anchorPointZ = Layer_Size/-2;
[rootLayer addSublayer:transformLayer];
```

the button no react

And when i do :

```
transformLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
[transformLayer addSublayer:test.layer];
transformLayer.anchorPointZ = Layer_Size/-2;
[self addSubview:test];
[rootLayer addSublayer:transformLayer];
```

the button react but don't move with the rest of the cube

I understand the problem but don't know how to fix it...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the difference between a UIButton, which inherits from UIResponder, and CALayer's, which do not make up a part of the responder chain directly.

Fortunately, there is a simple way to grab events from the responder chain and direct them towards your CALayer of choice, and it looks a little like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGPoint p = [(UITouch*)[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.worldView];
    for (CALayer *layer in self.worldView.layer.sublayers) {
        if ([layer containsPoint:[self.worldView.layer convertPoint:p toLayer:layer]]) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

It's the `containsPoint:convertPoint:toLayer:` that's going to hold the essence of what you seek.

There's [a bit more largely relevant discussion around this topic on this post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170288/trigger-an-action-when-a-calayer-is-touched)

To connect the dots of this to your invocation, when you add the button's layer to your other layers, all the visual aspects perform as expected, but no one is a member of the responder chain, and therefore no one receives touches to handle.

Comment: But with this code, how do you make a difference between the differents layers ? I mean, in the project that i've found, their is 6 different layers which creates the 3D cube, but how to know if it's the first or the second on which i've clicked ?

Comment: the call to [self.someView.layer convertPoint:somePoint toLayer:targetLayer] is taking care of converting a touch on a view to a coordinate on the layer. asking [layer containsPoint:convertedPoint]; will give you a yes or no answer about which layer that point is.